# Using "be out" to say that the subject/person is present

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I heard this "you were just out here". I looked up the meaning of "be out" and didn't find any phrasal verb indicating a special meaning. how would you interpret it?

1. you were not here but outside, or
2. you were here a moment ago

Comment: It's not a phrasal verb, just a regular one:  You were somewhere.  Where?  Out here.

Comment: Many (perhaps even *most*) instances of [***he was really out there***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+was+really+out+there%22) in Google Books are highly metaphoric usages meaning he was ***heavily under the influence of drugs and/or behaving outlandishly***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is literal. "Here" has the conventional meaning of the current place, the place where we are now. "Out" means outside of some other place under discussion, or out doors, i.e. as opposed to inside a building. "Just" means very recently.

So "You were just out here" means you were very recently in this place which is outdoors or distinct from some other place.

The only really ambiguous part is "out". Exactly what it means depends on context.

If you were at a party and a bunch of you were gathered outside the house, then someone went inside the house, then came back out, you might say, "Oh, you were just out here", that is, outside the house.

If a place is remote, like not in the big city, or not the main office of the company, or not the main building of some large complex, if someone was there, left, and came back you might say "You were just out here". "Out" in this case meaning "outside of the big place" or "the main place".

Answer (score 0):

Without additional context, I cannot reliably interpret the statement:

> you were just out here

It could mean any of:

> - You were outside a short time ago.
> - You were in this part of the country recently.
> - You were only present outside, you weren't doing {some specific action}.
> - You were in this part of the area, you weren't over in that other part.

Both "just" and "out here" can be taken in different ways, depending on the context. The word "just" can mean "a short tiem ago" or it can mean "only" with implication of "and not some other thing". The words "out here" can refer to a particular part of a yard, or a particular part of a region or country. Combined these ambiguities give rise to many possible meanings.

I would suggest that rather than looking up "be out", you research "out here". But better yet, provide as much additional context as possible.